# XslTransformException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, xslt, runtime-error

I am getting an error which I have not encountered in the past (and cannot find a solution after searching) .

Error Message: XslTransformException was unhandled by user code: Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace **'uri:PhysKare.Framework.Authentication.IUserAuthenticate'**.

Error details:

```
   at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.InvokeXsltLateBoundFunction(String name, String namespaceUri, IList`1[] args)
   at <xsl:template match="/">(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at Execute(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlSequenceWriter results)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results, XmlResolver documentResolver)
   at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(IXPathNavigable input, XsltArgumentList arguments, XmlWriter results)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Hello.

Post the xslt file.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Your XSLT uses custom functions in the namespace `uri:PhysKare.Framework.Authentication.IUserAuthenticate`, and you did not pass to the XSLT processor an object implementing these functions - i.e. you should do something like this:

```
  XsltArgumentList args = new XsltArgumentList();
  args.AddExtensionObject("uri:PhysKare.Framework.Authentication.IUserAuthenticate", new PhysKare());
  compiledXslt.Transfor(source, args, dest)
```

where `PhysKare` is a class implementing the custom functions used in the XSLT.